# Show if $f_x \rightarrow \eta \,\,\,$ and $g_x \rightarrow \zeta$ so $f_x+g_x \rightarrow \eta + \zeta$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, nets

Let $(f_x)$ and $(g_x)$ be two nets on a directed set $X$.

Show if $f_x \rightarrow \eta \,\,\,$ and $g_x \rightarrow \zeta$ so $f_x+g_x \rightarrow \eta + \zeta$

---

For $(f_x)$ holds:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\,\, \exists x_1 \in X\,\,\, \forall x\in X:x \succ x_1 \Longrightarrow |f_x-\eta|<\epsilon$$

And for $(g_x)$ holds:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\,\, \exists x_2 \in X\,\,\, \forall x\in X:x \succ x_2 \Longrightarrow |g_x-\zeta|<\epsilon$$

From the 3rd axiom of directed sets we know:

$$\forall x,y \in X \,\,\,\exists z\in X: z\succ x \,\,\wedge\,\, z\succ y$$

This means

$$\exists x_3 \in X: x_3\succ x_1 \,\,\wedge\,\, x_3\succ x_2$$

So:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\,\, \exists x_3 \in X\,\,\, \forall x\in X:x \succ x_3 \Longrightarrow|f_x-\eta|<\epsilon$$

and

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\,\, \exists x_3 \in X\,\,\, \forall x\in X:x \succ x_3 \Longrightarrow|g_x-\zeta|<\epsilon$$

$$|(f_x+g_x)-(\eta+\zeta)|=|(f_x-\eta)+(g_x-\zeta)|\le |f_x-\eta|+|g_x-\zeta|<2\epsilon$$

Lets call $\vartheta:=2\epsilon$

$$\Longrightarrow \forall \vartheta > 0 \,\,\, \exists x_3 \in X\,\,\, \forall x\in X:x \succ x_3 \Longrightarrow|(f_x+g_x)-(\eta+\zeta)|<\vartheta$$

Since the limit is distinct.

$$f_x+g_x \rightarrow \eta+\zeta$$

$\Box$

---

Would be great if someone could look over it, and give me feedback, if my work is correct, and if not, what I should improve! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost correct but you shouldn't say call $\nu=2\epsilon$. You should  start with $\nu >0$ and  take $\epsilon =\frac { \nu} 2$ in your argument.